# LTspice, Variable Resistor

Tags: power-supply, dc, ltspice, linear-regulator

I am new to LTspice and creating circuits in the application. I want to make a variable resistor to test and observe a current limiter circuit in a DC power supply. For example, it starts at 10 ohms and incrementally decreases to .1 ohms. Can that be done? Ideally, I want to see a plot of the current peak (current limit) and then fold back to a safe current with a short or low resistance.

Answer (score 2):

In LTSpice, you can sweep through values of a component. So for your case, you'd want to do:

```
.step param R1 [start value] [final value] [increment/decrement size]
```

This along with this, you'll also want another command:

```
.meas I1 peak I(R1)
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried (.step param R16 10 ohms .1 ohms .1) and received a pop-up error box stating .step syntax error "Expected end Value; Accept Anyway?" Any idea where I went wrong?

Comment: OK I got it entered but does not do anything that I can tell. I entered: .step param R16 10 .1 .1, but when I hit run, it looks like it uses whatever value I show in R16 in the circuit. I am missing something. How do I marry R16 with the Step parameter?  Thanks again.

Comment: @Dereck This answer uses the `.meas` command method, which requires you to pull up the SPICE Error Log after the simulation runs (CTRL+L) to see the result. If you want to look at the result directly you should do something like `.step param myValue 10 0.1 0.1` and then change R16’s **value** to `{myValue}`

Comment: @Ste Kulov thank you. I am still missing something. I tried what you suggested .step param myValue 10 0.1 0.1 and then replaced the R16 Ohmic value with myValue. When I click run, I get two popups, "Can't find the definition of model "MYVALUE," and the second popup is, "Missing Resistance Value R16. 

I must have been missing something and did not follow directions. If I specify a resistance for R16, the circuit runs. When I looked at the error log, it counted down from 10 to .1, and there is no current in R1 with .meas. It tells me the step directive did not assign the variable to anything.

Comment: @Dereck You need the curly braces. I put them there on purpose.

Comment: @Ste Kulov, thank you. I figured it out and have that part working. Now, I am trying to get a .meas directive to work. I want to measure the current in R16 for each step value. 

Someone was kind enough to suggest ".meas I1 peak I(R1)." I do get a printout of 0.00 for all step parameters. I do not know the command well enough to make it work. I changed I1 to I16 and R1 to R16, but it did not. Can you offer any suggestions, please?

Comment: @Dereck I’m not too familiar with `.meas`. I’ve been using LTspice for 14 years and only needed to use that command once. I believe it’s overused and mostly unnecessary. You should be able to do an `.op` simulation and simply click on R16 to plot the current across your stepped resistances. Honestly, I don’t think the syntax for the `.meas` In this answer is correct.